# How to specify the stiffener for ordering Flex-PCBs at JLCPCB

Tags: pcb, pcb-fabrication, fpc, flexible

I have a Flex-PCB design that contains several areas that are supported by stiffeners. I am trying to order the PCB at JLCPCB but can not figure out how to specify the areas where the stiffener is applied.

This is the only hint I could find on their website:

[image]

There was [a similar question](https://jlc3dp.com/help/answers/detail/99-Technical-questions-on-Flex-PCB) asked on their forums and their answer was

> You can define it in the silkscreen layer. Or you add a new layer to
> define.

When I tried adding a custom layer like in their example, their gerber viewer did not show any stiffener. But they did not even specify what name that layer should have...

Does anyone know how to order stiffener?

Comment: If the gerber layer is included, it should be fine. Make sure to **tell them what you want** with words..Maybe use their chat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tried it out and it worked:

I used KiCad and added a custom layer "Stiffener". In that layer I drew the outlines of the areas that need stiffener applied using the "Draw a line", "Draw an arc", "Draw a rectangle"... tools (similar to how you draw your board outline on the Edge.Cuts layer).
In addition I placed a text ("Add a text item") in the Stiffener layer close to the outline:

> Stiffener: Polyimide
>
> Thickness: 0.25mm

Obviously when ordering select the stiffener option...

**Note on the "Fabrication"-Plugin:**
There is a popular plugin for KiCad that automatically generates gerber-files with the correct settings for JLCPCB. This does not work as it will not generate a gerber-file for the stiffener layer.

Instead follow this guide and in addition to the mentioned layers also select the "Stiffner" layer.:
https://jlcpcb.com/help/article/362-how-to-generate-gerber-and-drill-files-in-kicad-7

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the file extension is .GTSL for the Gerber file describing top-placed stiffeners. .GBSL - for the bottom-placed stiffeners. Likely the stiffeners should be shown as filled polygons (e.g. rectangles) on these layers.

The following WEB page sheds some light on JLCPCB naming rules for the stiffener layers

https://jlcpcb.com/help/article/495-easyeda-flex-pcb-design-user-guide

One small note regarding the idea to "tell them what you want with words".
https://jlcpcb.com/help/article/14-Instructions-for-ordering clearly says "The English descriptions and other statements in your zip file <...> will be disregarded"

Comment: The gerber file endings are not universal afaik. And if there are ambiguities, they would be stupid to just do what they guess. They will and do seek clarification. If you wanna go sure you get the right thing, you provide as much as possible clarification..Their note is obviously just a legal safety net.